# xml attribute to element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input xml:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <fde-request xmlns="http://xml-schemas.xxx.com/bb/xxx.xsd"
        xmlns:cbe="http://xml-schemas.xxx.com/bb/xxx.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml-schemas.xxx.com/bb/xxx.xsd xxx.xsd">

        <cbe:request-header
        user-id="mde"
        session-token="433"
        audit-id="9999"
        pearl-code="ca"
        interface-id="mf"
        system-name="sr"
        function-code="image"
        />

    <fde-parms
      function-code='b'
      sccf-serial='042463452400'
      type-process='H'>
    </fde-parms>
    </fde-request>
```

I need to get the following output xml by copying attribute to new element values:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <fde-request xmlns="http://xml-schemas.xxx.com/bb/xxx.xsd"
        xmlns:cbe="http://xml-schemas.xxx.com/bb/xxx.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml-schemas.xxx.com/bb/xxx.xsd xxx.xsd">

         <REQUEST-HEADER>
      <REQUEST-ID>mde</REQUEST-ID>
      <REQUEST-PEACODE>ca</REQUEST-PEACODE>
       </REQUEST-HEADER> 

    <fde-parms
      function-code='b'
      sccf-serial='042463452400'
      type-process='H'>
    </fde-parms>
    </fde-request>
```

BUT: I am getting this output xml with the following xslt:

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="*[local-name(.)='request-header']">
        <xsl:variable name="sysname" select="@system-name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="peacode" select="@pearl-code"/>

    <REQUEST-HEADER>
    <REQUEST-ID><xsl:value-of select="$sysname"/></REQUEST-ID>
    <REQUEST-PEACODE><xsl:value-of select="$peacode"/></REQUEST-PEACODE>
    </REQUEST-HEADER>   
        </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

That produces the wrong output: `xmlns=""` is populating, which is not what I want.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <fde-request xmlns="http://xml-schemas.xxx.com/bb/xxx.xsd"
        xmlns:cbe="http://xml-schemas.xxx.com/bb/xxx.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml-schemas.xxx.com/bb/xxx.xsd xxx.xsd">

         <REQUEST-HEADER **xmlns=""**>
      <REQUEST-ID>mde</REQUEST-ID>
      <REQUEST-PEACODE>ca</REQUEST-PEACODE>
       </REQUEST-HEADER> 

    <fde-parms
      function-code='b'
      sccf-serial='042463452400'
      type-process='H'>
    </fde-parms>
    </fde-request>
```

I need to remove this unnecessary empty namespace.
How would you modify the xslt to produce the right output?

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 1.0 (which I assume you're using; your example stylesheet is missing the start tag), `xsl:copy` always [copies](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) all namespace nodes too.

If you want to avoid copying a namespace, you need to recreate the element using [`xsl:element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl%3aelement). Its `namespace` attribute is optional.